# Filtering Django query filtering

Tags: django, database

I'm doing some querying currently and I was wondering if I would be able to query something from these 3 models where the return would give me all the projects the users are working on. I know about the basic filtering however thats not really enough in this case, how would one go about querying through 2 foreign keys.

```
class User(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    email = models.EmailField()

class ProjectUser(models.Model):
    project = models.ForeignKey("Project", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user = models.ForeignKey("User", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    is_lead = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = (("project", "user"),)

class Project(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    client = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    complete = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

Comment: So you have a user and you want all the `Project`s that user is working on?

Comment: Yeah exactly, I wanted to get the query so then I can transform it into a JSON.

Answer (score 2):

You can obtain the `Project`s a *`user`* is working on with:

```
Project.objects.filter(
    projectuser__user=user
)
```

The double underscores are used to look "*through*" relations. Furthermore the default [**`related_query_name=…`** parameter [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_query_name) is, if not specified, the name of the model in lowercase.

Comment: You're missing the suffix `_set` for the default `related_name`.

Comment: @schillingt: no, the query does not *use* `related_name`, it uses `related_query_name` in the filtering :) The confusion comes from the fact that if you specify a `related_name`, and no `related_query_name`, then it will indeed use the `related_name`. But if you do not specify any of the two, it uses the name of the model in lowercase.

Comment: @schillingt: see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_query_name where it shows how `related_query_name` is used in queries, and `related_name` as the name of the reverse *manager*.

Comment: So for every double __ you're able to look further into the databse if the fields are connected?

Comment: @Karna: yes, basically you can think of `__` as some sort of `LEFT OUTER JOIN`: https://www.dofactory.com/sql/left-outer-join

Comment: Hmm, that documentation isn't written very clearly. I'm not 100% sure it's talking about the default being set, or either of the default and `related_name` being set.

Comment: @schillingt: well, I've tested this already (you can simply make a toy project and use two models). Normally it will work with the model name in lowercase. If no `related_query_name` or `related_name` is set, nor `default_related_name` (which is set for model inheritance), it will use the model name in lowercase.

Comment: TIL. Thanks @WillemVanOnsem